# Why may be the reason fo helm_resource in terraform script being terribly slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I've a terraform script for my AWS EKS cluster and the following pieces there:

```
provider "helm" {
  alias = "helm"
  debug = true
  kubernetes {
    host                   = module.eks.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = module.eks.ca_certificate
    token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
    load_config_file       = false
  }
}
```

and:

```
resource "helm_release" "prometheus_operator" {
  provider   = "helm"
  depends_on = [
    module.eks.aws_eks_auth
  ]
  chart      = "stable/prometheus-operator"
  name       = "prometheus-operator"
  values     = [
    file("staging/prometheus-operator-values.yaml")
  ]
  wait       = false
  version    = "8.12.12"
}
```

With this setup it takes ~15 minutes to install the required chart with terraform apply and sometimes it fails (with `helm ls` giving `pending-install` status). On the other hand if use the following command:

```
helm install prometheus-operator stable/prometheus-operator -f staging/prometheus-operator-values.yaml --version 8.12.12 --debug
```

the required chart gets installed in ~3 minutes and never fails. What is the reason for this behavior?

**EDIT**

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/random/blob/master/tf-po.log) is a log file from a failed installation. It's quit big - 5.6M. What bothers me a bit is located in line no `47725` and `56045`

What's more, `helm status prometheus-operator` gives valid output (as if it was successfully installed), however there're no pods defined.

**EDIT 2**

I've also raised an [issue](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/21913).

Comment: If you run Terraform with debug logging do you see anything useful? If so could you add it to the question please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, thanks for the comment. I haven't noticed anything strange, but I'll prepare the log.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, I've provided a log file from a failed installation.